# How to Encode a text using base64_encode() , So that it can't be decoded

Tags: base64, decode, encode

I just want to know how to secure a text using base64_encode() , so that it can't be decoded properly from base64_decode().

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text and encode it this way you simply change the byte sequence but it always can be transformed back into its original form; so you cannot stop people from doing it.

You could introduce errors into the base64 encoded form to stop the decode function to work but this is not at all secure.

To stop people from reading the text you could encrypt it and then base64 encode the encrypted form.

Comment: Generally you cannot know without having extra information, like looking not only at the encrypted information but also how it is transported which can give good starting points to attack. "Attacking an encoding" is kind of a simple attack since it is computationally easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to make sure your data can never be decoded.

```
import random

def secureEncode(s):
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890/+'
    length = int(len(s)*4./3)
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in xrange(length))
```

In all seriousness, you seem to be completely missing the point. Base64 is a data format. The whole point is that you can get the data back. If you want to destroy data, just destroy it.

If you want to hide your data in a way that it can only be read if you know a secret, you need to look into encryption.